# Для каких натуральных n выражение 2^n + 8n + 5 точный квадрат?

Tags: математика

Задача(написана в заголовке):
Для каких натуральных n выражение 2^n + 8n + 5 точный квадрат?

Решить можно даже со знаниями 8-9 класса школьной математики.

Comment: Разъясните математический термин "точный квадрат"

Comment: Если коротко, то корень из этого числа даёт целое число.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да все просто. Пусть это выражение - квадрат. Тогда это квадрат нечетного числа (слева-то нечетное).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Преобразуя (самостоятельно!), получаем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева - четное число (самостоятельно сообразите, почему). Справа - при `n > 2` - нечетное. Значит, при `n > 2` ничего не выйдет...

И только при `n=2` имеем справа тоже четное.

Подставляя в вашу формулу, находим единственное решение 2^2+8*2+5=4+16+5=25...

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё сам понял, кроме одного момента. В последней строчке, почему мы уверены, что справа нечетное? А нет, только, что доперло, ещё раз спасибо.